# Can i copy directory using Phonegap/cordova framework?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, blackberry, cordova-2.0.0

i want copy one directory from one location to another location.
i research on that i found **copyTo** Api. In that document i found  quick example from doc as below

```
function win(entry) {
    console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}

function copyDir(entry) {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value,
        newName = document.getElementById('newName').value,
        parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry({fullPath: parent});

    // copy the directory to a new directory and rename it
    entry.copyTo(parentEntry, newName, success, fail);
}
```

Now how i am confuse where is source path variable and what is destination path variable?
can any one provide me one good example for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope the following helps your understanding:

```
var root;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        root = fileSystem.root;
        // get the directory we want to get within the root directory
        var srcDir = 'srcDir'; 
        root.getDirectory(srcDir, {create: false}, getDirectoryWin, getDirectoryFail);
});

// the directory param should be a DirectoryEntry object that points to the srcDir    
function getDirectoryWin(directory){
    console.log('got the directory');

    // path to the parent directory that holds the dir that we want to copy to
    // we'll set it as the root, but otherwise you'll
    // need parentDir be a DirectoryEntry object
    var parentDir = root;

    // name of the destination directory within the parentDir
    var dstDir = 'dstDir'; 

    // use copyWin/copyFail to launch callbacks when it works/fails
    directory.copyTo(root, dstDir, copyWin, copyFail);
}

function getDirectoryFail(){
    console.log("I failed at getting a directory");
}

function copyWin(){
    console.log('Copying worked!');
}

function copyFail(){
    console.log('I failed copying');
}
```

Comment: Tim, do you know why I'm getting error 5 if trying to copy  "file:///android_asset/www" directory? specifying relative path works well but I need to copy directories that are next to my cordova index.html